# Why is the following Meteor change event not working?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want the alert to trigger each time the I type on `.simditor-body`:

[image]

```
Template.postSubmit.events({
  "change .simditor-body": function() {
    alert("worked");
  }
});
```

But right now nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `change` event on `contenteditable` so you should be using `keypress` event like:

```
Template.postSubmit.events({
  "keypress .simditor-body": function() {
    alert("worked");
  }
});
```

Also check http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html for DOM event compatibality with browsers and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events for a list of available events.